# Is “since-folded (TV network)” an accustomed English word?

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

In its Entertainment TV section, [Time magazine](http://time.com/3044887/sarah-palin-has-launched-her-own-internet-television-network/?xid=newsletter-brief) (August 29) reports that Sara Palin has launched her own Internet Television network. It says;

> Palin’s not the first candidate to lose an election and then embrace the media. Aug. 1 marks the ninth anniversary of the launch of Current TV, Al Gore’s **since-folded** television network, which Al Jazeera bought last year.

I was attracted to the word, “**since-folded**,” and I thought it convenient word to be used in many other ways, like “since-folded shop/hospital/library/hotel/company/program,” and so on.

So I checked OED, CED, and Merriam-Webster English Dictionary to make certain. None of them carries “since-folded,” nor does Google Ngram.

How does "since-folded" differ from "long-folded (closed/non-operating)"?

Is “since-folded” an 'accustomed' English word, or just one-off coinage of the article author, P.Nash Jenkins?

Comment: I wouldn't take that usage as indicative of the primary "productive" version. Most people would probably go with ***now-folded***, which applies in far more contexts. The only justification for using ***since-*** instead of ***now-*** is when you want to call attention to *the event itself* (the folding, in this case). In most cases even a past tense verb like that is primarily indicating the *current state*, and therefore it would more naturally be a ***now-closed*** network, not a ***since-closed*** one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure I think that distinction is relevant. My problem is with 'folded'. I suffer the disadvantage of having been an accountant, and the word's a bit too colloquial for me. I might speak of a now-closed, or since-closed, operation. A 'wound-up' company also has a definite legal meaning. But there is probably nothing terribly wrong with 'folded' - just that my preference would be elsewhere.

Comment: @WS2: Well, I'm not wild about *folded* myself, which is why I switched to *closed* (*defunct* isn't bad either). But I think the distinction *is* relevant if you consider other adjectival past tenses that might be used in similar ways. If I speak of a *since-arrested thief* it's even possible that *by the time of speaking* he might have been tried, convicted, served his time, and be out on parole. But if I say a *now-arrested thief* you can be pretty certain he's somewhere between having been arrested and having been convicted (because I'm describing his *current* state).

Comment: Hey Yoichi -- it's a very-obvious combination in English.  it's one of those weird things that is probably not common (it would be hard to find examples of it, I bet) but it's absolutely obvious and clear to any English speaker.  "since-blah" is common and as Fumble explains "blah-closed" etc are all common.

Comment: WS and Fumble - I'm surprised you're surprised by "folded". it's the usual slightly-pejorative choice in tabloid-esque writing, since it makes the company sound more like a flop or failure.  (Yoichi - I'm sure you could find humorous usages like "since-fucked-up" or "since-screwed-the-pooch" .. company. You'd probably also see "since-exploded" "since-evaporated" and so on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a combination of adverb describing a participial-adjective.

The following are examples of adjectives derived from verbs, hence participle+adjective.

Past completed/perfected participles

- *painted* door
- *discarded* food
- *targeted* audience
- *folded* business.

Present progressing participles

- *running* man
- *traveling* salesman
- *closing* sale
- *folding* chair

We could attach another adjective to describe how the fore-front adjective describes its noun.

- tall painted door
- smelly discarded food
- handsome traveling salesman.

OTOH, we could attach an adverb to describe how an adjective achieved its state

- *quickly* painted door
- *unscrupulously* discarded food
- *fast*-traveling salesman
- *fast*-moving van
- *duly*-noted heroism

Therefore, we could also use conjunctive adverbs to describe the adjective's achieving its state

- thus discarded food
- since folded business
- also-included reference letter
- hence-unrequited love
- thence-unrequited love
- likewise receded tumour
- otherwise-unnoticed genius
- she was then-unmarried Drew Barrymore
- the instead-of untainted replacement
- next-completed action item  (vs next completed-action-item)
- she spilled the still-brewing tea.

Conjunctive adverb vs conjunctive adjective

- your nonetheless-perfected record should not be ruined
- your nonetheless-healthy lungs should not be subjected to stress anyway .

**Appendix**:
I did not expect this to be chosen the answer. I wrote this answer purely to remind (and educate those who did not know) of the grammatical elements of the situation.

My since-chosen answer obliges me to explain the difference between *since-defunct* vs *now-defunct*, by pointing out what it means to be a conjunctive adverb/adjective.

A conjunction connects two predicates. Therefore, a conjunctive adverb connects the action of the current new story to the effects of actions that took place in an existing story.

It is meaningless to have the conjunction in the story:

> My *since*-reduced role in the company has been free from the burdens of responsibility

Unless it is preceded or followed by the likes of

> having resigned as chair of the board

There is difference between jail time and walking free to say

> My now-reduced role would not allow me the privilege of such decisions

vs

> My since-reduced role would not allow me the privilege of such decisions

When asked by the prosecutor in court

> Did you over-see the release of toxic waste into the river after your resignation from the chair of the board?

Further examples

- Person 1: Prince Charming bent to kiss Snow White.
  Person 2: Whereas the thus-broken spell continued to haunt her memories.
- P1: Don't you know the messiah has come to save the world?
  P2: But I'm afraid, such hence-perceived superstition removes from men their responsibility to save the planet from climate disaster.

Comment: Though meaning are all obvious, I feel the words of [adverb＋noun compound] you quoted such as “since-folded,” “hence-unrequited love,” “hence-unrequited love” are somewhat alien in contrast to the [adjective＋noun] compound such as “tall painted door,” “handsome traveling salesman,” “fast-moving van,” which are familiar to me.
I don’t know why.

Comment: [[adverb+adjective]+noun] vs [adjective + [adjective+noun]]

Comment: In the category under OTOH, I am not sure why you hyphenated three of them, but not the other two. And the reason that a *fast-travelling salesman* gets hyphenated, whilst a *handsome travelling salesman* doesn't, is simply that *fast* describes *travelling*, but *handsome* describes *salesman*.

Comment: Hyphenating a pair of words is the way to increase the proximity of those two words above other neighbouring words. You could always hyphenate to ensure the proximity is obvious. But hyphenation is a strategy not a rule, so that if the proximity is understood without hyphenation, you don't need to hyphenate. Hyphenation is a strategy not a rule.

Comment: I feel this answer completely misses the point. "since-blah" is a common form, it's that simple. it's a bit of journalese, if you will.  sure, everyone realises what speech parts they are.

Answer (score 10):

Here "since-folded" means "having folded since some previously mentioned event" not just "having folded previously". In this case, "Aug. 1 marks the ninth anniversary of the launch of Current TV, Al Gore’s since-folded television network, which Al Jazeera bought last year" could have been written as "Aug. 1 marks the ninth anniversary of the launch of Current TV, Al Gore's television network which has since folded, and which Al Jazeera bought last year". Obviously my version is more awkward, which is why it was published as written.

In any case, this is just an example of a compound attributive modifier ("since" + "folded"), which is hyphenated by the normal rules for compound modifiers used attributively. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier

Comment: @YoichiOishi - You can use the same construction with many other past participles/adjectives, e.g. "Martin stared at the faded fascia board of the long-since-defunct general store". I'd say it appears more in print than in speech, however, so it's best used sparingly.

Comment: @Erik: I think you can only really shoehorn ***since*** alongside ***defunct*** when you also stick ***long*** on the front. Most people would just use ***now-defunct***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Agreed. I chose a poor example.

Comment: @Erik: In some ways it's a *good* example, because it forces us to wonder what it is about the bare *since-defunct* that we don't like. Which imho is that ***since-*** focusses on a *past event*, but ***defunct*** is more a state than an event. Yet when we switch to ***long-since***, it suddenly becomes okay, because that version means *it's been in that state for a long time*. Any specific "event" that might have caused it to enter that state is only peripherally alluded to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's strange, isn't it, that *since-defunct* strikes a false note, whereas *since-abandoned* in the same context sounds OK?

Comment: I must say I don't like OP's example much, and would have preferred *now-folded* or similar. The thing is, the "since some previously mentioned event" in this case is just the launch of the network anyway. If the only "past event" you can dig up to co-reference with a "now-non-existent" thing is the *creation* of that thing, it hardly seems worth bothering to mention.

Comment: It's not in the slightest strange.  It has to be since-some-action.  (since-abandoned, since-exploded, since-flopped etc)  since-defunct makes no sense - it would be like saying "since-red" or "since-big".

Answer (score 2):

The since is an interesting **reference to a time span outside** of what is described:

In
`... launch of Current TV, Al Gore’s since-folded television network ...`
the `since` refers to the **time span** between what is described **in the sentence**, and the **time of writing**:

I would expand the sentence to
`... launch of "Current TV", Al Gore’s television network, which folded since that time, ...`
So the TV station closed down, but not at the time we're writing about, but between then, and now, when we are describing it.
All that is a side note, on a meta level.

---

I'll compare related words that came up, assuming the same context of the sentence where "since-folded" was used.
I use "then" for the time where the events occurred that are described in the original context sentence, "ninth anniversary of the launch of Current TV",
and "now" for the time of writing the sentence.

The meaning of **"since-folded"** is about the **same** as **"folded in the meantime"**, that is, folded between then, and now.

It is different from **"long-folded"**: folded before now, even long before, but - only implicitly - not before then.

It is also different from **"now-defunct"**: defunct before now, with no relation to then.

Comment: "folded in the meantime" also available

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, that matches closely. I'll compare it with some of the other words proposed.